# @ResponseBody not producing XML in Java 6

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, ibm-rad-7.5

I have a Spring MVC 3/J2EE Project.  The jsp rendering controllers are working fine, but the one controller that renders XML for Ajax is not working.  I am using JDK 1.6 in RAD 7.5 so JAXB should be on the classpath, and I've even tried adding the latest JAXB jars to the lib file to make sure.  **I still get a 406 error when I make the call.**  My DOJO call has `handleAs: "xml"`, and I've confirmed that `application/xml` is on the `Accept` header via FireBug.  I have the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` line in my spring servlet xml file. I can see the method being invoked and returning without error.  I'm not sure what I should try next to debug.

```
//Country is a class with only primative types which implements Serializable.
public @ResponseBody List<Country> getCountries(){
    return addressService.getCountries();
}
```

---

```
function loadData(){
    console.log("Before get ...");
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"http://localhost:9080/sample/shared/getCountries.htm",
        handleAs:"xml",
        load: function(data){
            console.log("In load function ...");
            try {
                for(var i in data){
                   console.log("key", i, "value", data[i]);
                }
            }catch (ex){
                console.error("Failure in load function: " + ex);
            }
            console.log("Exiting load function ...");
        },
        error: function(x){
            console.error("Error in ajax ...");
            console.error(x);
        },
        failOk: false
    });
    console.log("After get ...");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating the following wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Countries {
    private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>()

    //getters/setters
}
```

And return it from the controller instead of a raw list:

```
public @ResponseBody Countries getCountries()
```

Most likely your problem is caused by JAXB that is unable to marshal Java list (it does not know how to name the root tag of the XML document). Note that your problem probably does not occur when requesting data in JSON (if Jackson is available on your CLASSPATH).

See also (similar problems):

- [Spring MVC 3: Returning XML through @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856298)
- [issues with xml in spring mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446342)

Comment: I would be surprised if this would cause the `406`, however, I agree that a wrapper is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this this in another answer. Trying it today.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing how you have configured your views / view resolvers. However, the client-side URL containing a `.htm` is suspect to me, especially if you are using a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. I recommend dropping the file extension. Browsers automatically use an `Accept` header for HTML so no need to use an extension.

Comment: Obviously the view resolver is working correctly since "I can see the method being invoked and returning without error."

Comment: Sorry, wasn't quite fast enough for you :-).

Comment: The "method returning" occurs before view resolution and thus is not an indicator of the server side being configured correctly.

Comment: `@ResponseBody` skips view resolution altogether.

Comment: No it doesn't. Try it. It exists for special circumstances, like returning a String that you want to go into the body instead of being interpreted as a view name. The framework will still pick a view to render (i.e. view resolution) based on configured views/resolvers.